# command id for maximizing the explorer (or sidebar) in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

##### Question:

How do I maximize either the explorer or the sidebar in vscode?

##### Background:

I did not find any command ids for this in either of the documents below. But neither claim to be comprehensive.

1. [list of internal commands](https://gist.github.com/skfarhat/4e88ef386c93b9dceb98121d9457edbf)
2. [getting started docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)